# Laravel: Query builder base query for different conditions

Tags: php, sql, laravel, query-builder, radix

In my application there is a situation where I have to run the same query 3 times but each query has some different conditions. For example: `active:` Query + `active conditions`, `inactive:` Query + `inactive conditions`. etc.

Here is my code:

```php
$activeInventory = $inactiveInventory = \DB::table('device_inventories')
  ->where([
    'device_companies.company_id'  => session()->get('COMPANY_ID'),
    'device_inventories.device_id' => $Self->id,
  ])->select([
    ...
  ])
  ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_inventories.device_id')
  ->join('device_companies', 'device_companies.id', '=', 'devices.device_company_id');

// active records
$active = $activeInventory
  ->where('device_inventories.status', 'T')
  ->join('u_devices', 'u_devices.device_inventory_id', '!=', 'device_inventories.id')
  ->get() ?? null;

// inactive records
$inactive = $inactiveInventory
  ->where('device_inventories.status', 'F')
  ->get() ?? null;

// returning data
return [
  'model' => $Self,
  'active' => $active,
  'inactive' => $inactive,
];
```

Notice that I have joined the `u_devices` table in the `Active` query. But when I am running the `Inactive` query that join with `u_devices` is also present in that query as well. Even when I am using different variables to store the base query and to running it.

What am I doing wrong here..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the way that appending query logic works. When you append changes to one version of the query, it modifies the original, so any subsequent queries from the base are also affected. You should be able to get this to work with the `clone` keyword in PHP:

```
$baseQuery = \DB::table('device_inventories')->where([
  'device_companies.company_id'  => session()->get('COMPANY_ID'),
  'device_inventories.device_id' => $Self->id,
])->select([
  ...
])
->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_inventories.device_id')
->join('device_companies', 'device_companies.id', '=', 'devices.device_company_id');

$active = (clone $baseQuery)->where('device_inventories.status', 'T')
->join('u_devices', 'u_devices.device_inventory_id', '!=', 'device_inventories.id')
->get() ?? null;

$inactive = (clone $baseQuery)->where('device_inventories.status', 'F')->get() ?? null;

return [
  'model' => $Self,
  'active' => $active,
  'inactive' => $inactive,
];
```

When you use `clone`, you create a copy of the query as it is at that point in your code, so subsequent uses do not "pollute" the query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a new instance of the builder object. `$activeInventory` is holding all the conditions you tell it to, which includes all the `where` conditions. You will want a copy of the builder to do a different query on it:

```
$something = (clone $activeInventory)->...;
$else = (clone $activeInventory)->...;
```